# Convert user define time to UTC using moment

Tags: node.js, momentjs

We have application where we ask user to define time when they want to publish some content. In our application, user will select that content should publish X(0-5) day before target date and y time (0-23).

So if user create a content with publish date = "09/21/2021" and publish time as 3 it means this content needs to publish at 3 AM on 09/21/2021.

In our Mongo DB we need to store the calculated date as "2021-09-21T07:00:00" So it can be pulled by our Cron Job.

We tried will following without any success

```js
          var promotedDate = "2021-08-19 04:00:00"
          var fmt = "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss";
          var m = moment.utc(promotedDate, fmt);
          console.log('promoted date ', tempDate)
          console.log(m.local().format(fmt));
          console.log(m.utc().format(fmt));
```

But it gives 2021-08-19 12:00:00

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`moment.toISOString()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/). That will give you UTC regardless of the timezone of the `moment` in question thus: `2013-02-04T22:44:30.652Z`.

Since that comes with milliseconds and a `Z` for Zulu time, we need to strip off the last 5 characters with `string.slice()`:

```js
const promotedDate = "2021-08-19 04:00:00";
const m            = moment.utc(promotedDate, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");
const iso8601      = m.toISOString()
                      .slice(0,-5); // removes milliseconds and `Z` for Zulu

console.log( `promoted: ${promotedDate}` );
console.log( `iso8601:  ${iso8601} );
```